# Kendo grid batch editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

Can I select multiple rows in a Kendo grid and edit its column value to some common value? So can I select 5 rows based on some common value for a column and update its value in one click ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported as a built-in feature but can be implemented using the API.

Here is a short example: http://jsbin.com/alocoj/1/edit